# Differentiating between global::System and foo.System in generated code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a multi-project solution in VS 2015. One of the projects is `foo.System`, which you may have noticed creates some potential confusion between that and, y'know, `System`. This is causing issues in the Component Designer generated code when something like

```
this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
```

gives the error `The type or namespace name 'ServiceProcess' does not exist in the namespace 'Tapestry.System'` because the compiler then looks for ServiceProcess in `foo.System` instead of `System`.

Obviously I can edit the generated code to clarify (as explained in the answers in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373553/the-type-or-namespace-name-componentmodel-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-afte)), but those changes will get overwritten next time the code is generated. Is there any way to fix this short of insisting to my boss that we rename `foo.System`?

Comment: Rename it. It's not worth the eternity of trouble. Many years ago I watched my .NET instructor fumble around for 10 minutes in front of a class because she was trying to use a framework `Color` enum in a class or namespace she had named `Color`. She eventually gave up without ever realizing what the problem was.

Comment: Two identifier names are reserved to the framework, Microsoft and System.  Fix the real problem.

Comment: Fair enough. Make that an answer, and I'll accept it.

Comment: As it's been over a week, I've written and accepted my own answer. Should one of you return and post your own answer, I'll accept that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in comments by Scott Hannen and Hans Passant, regardless of any other answer to my question that may exist, the **real** answer is to rename foo.System. (For info on that process see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/224788/2308973)
 to "How to rename a Project Folder from within Visual Studio?")